# Real Time Game Center game disconnects (possibly because of network timeout)

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, game-center, gamekit

So, I'm writing a very simple real time game center 2-player game; however, the problem is I keep getting disconnected.

The game works as follows: Each player has a text field on their device.  They each enter text in the field and press enter.  When both people have inputted text, the game progresses.

**Now, when the users are actively playing the game (inputting text every 10 seconds or so), the game works just fine and a user has never been disconnected.  However, when the game remains inactive (the user just sits and stares at the app screen) for about 30 seconds or more, at least one player gets disconnected.**

I'm pretty confident that my Internet is solid and both devices appear to be connected to the Internet (via wifi).

I know this is a very vague question, I was just wondering if anyone has any ideas related to the symptoms in bold above.

EDIT:

Here's how I initialize the matchrequest and the match.  However, I'm having no trouble initializing or starting the match.  The only problem is when a player goes idle for some length of time

```
//toInvite may be nil
- (void) createMatchWithPlayersToInvite: (NSArray *) toInvite
{
    GKMatchRequest *request = [[GKMatchRequest alloc] init];
    request.minPlayers = 2;
    request.maxPlayers = 2;
    request.playersToInvite = toInvite;
    GKMatchmakerViewController *mmvc = [[GKMatchmakerViewController alloc] initWithMatchRequest:request];
    self.myMatchmakerVC = mmvc;
    mmvc.hosted = NO;
    mmvc.matchmakerDelegate = self;
    [self presentViewController:mmvc animated:YES completion:nil];
}


- (void)matchmakerViewController:(GKMatchmakerViewController *)viewController didFindMatch:(GKMatch *)match
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    self.myMatch = match;
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    appDelegate.currentMatch = self.myMatch;
    if (!self.matchStarted && match.expectedPlayerCount == 0)
    {
        self.matchStarted = YES;
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"gameSegue" sender:self];
    }
}
```

EDIT 2:

**So, I've discovered that if I set a timer and send messages across the network (with [self.myMatch sendDataToAllPlayers:data withDataMode:GKMatchSendDataReliable error:&error])  every 1 second, the program works just fine.  Does anyone have idea why this is or how I can fix my issue without resorting to a hacked together `NSTimer`?**
Other notes:

1) My `AppDelegate` has not been changed

Comment: Sorry, but you are going to need to provide a lot more information for someone to be able to answer this question. There are just too many variables that we, as complete strangers to your project, do not know. I would start with the code that you make the connection with.

Comment: Yes, I realize that my question is very vague, I was just hoping that someone would recognize the idle player issue.  I've added the code where I start the match above.  Thanks

Comment: The hack is not your use of `NSTimer`. In fact, the API you are using is intended for a game loop sending messages at a high rate, e.g. player positions. It is highly unusual for this to be driven by rare UI events, so an `NSTimer` is an appropriate workaround if you are being timed out. What's really a hack here is the use of a realtime API for something that could rather follow a push model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you have a clear hypothesis here, i.e. that Game Center connections are closed after 30 seconds idle time. I would not be surprised if this is the case. Other games almost certainly will send data within such an interval, and you may be triggering a timeout condition. To test this hypothesis and fix the problem at the same time, I would send a short blind text every five or ten seconds.

Comment: Ok, I've tested out your theory and got curious results.  So, if I set the timer for every 5 or 10 seconds it fails.  However, if I set it for every 1 second it works fine.  I've been able to idle the program for over 8 minutes with no issues.  Do you have an idea how to solve this timeout issue without hacking together a timer?  If not, the timer solution will work just fine.  Thanks!

Comment: I'm afraid I don't. I think it is very common to send messages many times per second, and perhaps expected. There is no `GKErrorTimeout` you could check for either.

Comment: In scenarios where there are long delays between messages it's usually a good idea to send "ping" or "keep-alive" packages. GameCenter is using UDP, so there could be NAT and other networking issues.